# How much can a message size increase by adding the '[Serializable]' attribute to a C# class?

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes, xml-serialization

I have a UI and WS solution. And on the start up of the UI, it loads in some data from the WS (Web Service). In the UI config (previously) we had maxReceivedMessageSize="131072", and all was working fine. I then added the '[Serializable]' attribute to my classes, and then received an error:

`QuotaExceededException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (131072) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.`

I then upped this to 262144, and then it started working again.

To clarify, on the initial load of data from the WS, I am not actually doing any serialization. The attribute was just added for another method, which doesn't get called on the start up of the solution.

So I'm wondering, how much could my message size have increased by? Is it a fixed multiplier, or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Unclear how it was serialized before. Normally I wouldn't expect an increase in size at all.

Comment: So the initial load of data doesn't use any serialization, this was only added for another method in another part of the application. So it seamed, just by adding the attribute, that the sizes of the messages are increasing, before actually performing any serialization.

Comment: It is unclear how your messages are serialized (before/after). Try to  write up an [mcve].

Comment: Also, be very clear about which APIs you are using, and which version(s). WS sounds like  ASMX.

Comment: You have a web application which has a Request and a Response.  So the size is the max Response size which a has nothing to do with the serialization part of the code.